# BeautifulSoup not working on this website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# HTML From Website
url = "https://myaeon2go.com/product/11073/local-tomato"

#convert soup to readable html
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

prices = doc.find_all("span", {"class": "oVW2jqeJPDfka7D8UVAd"})
rm = doc.find_all(text="RM")

print(prices)
```

Ive been trying to wrap my head around this code, but even if i tried looking for other elements the classes are all randomly generated. The code just outputs [] . Not sure why that is?

Comment: The classes are likely programmatically generated by a transpiler or similar tool for optimizations or to prevent this type of scraping behavior (or both). You’ll have to architect a different method of finding the elements you need in the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is modal window (location overlay) with input of postal code which pop-up when script request the page. You can pass cookies which suppress window when requesting like this:

```
...
cookies = {'hideLocationOverlay': 'true', 'selectedShippingState': 'Pulau Pinang', 'selectedPostalCode': '14000'}
    
#convert soup to readable html
result = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

...
```

To find the price I would recommend this approach:

```
price = doc.find("div", {"data-bx": "pdp-details-price"}).find("span").find("span").text

print(price)
```

Comment: The code seems to work thanks! how did you identify that it had to retrieve the cookie of location in order for it to work?

Comment: First time i opened the window in normal mode. Then i opened the window again and the popup didn't appear anymore. In the private mode of the browser, the pop-up is always displayed. This means that the site must store cookies in the browser, so I viewed the cookies stored by the site and tried to pass them to the request library :)